# Is there any iOS API for credit card transaction?

Tags: ios

I am working on a Point of Sale app in which buyers can pay via paypal or credit card. I found there are some implementation of paypal transaction. Can anyone help me to implement credit card transaction by reading the credit card details?

Comment: GIYF (Google Is Your Friend) http://www.ipcprint.com/mobile/products/barcode-scanners/linea-pro-4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you selling any physical goods? If not, I would look into the iOS in-app-purchase program.

Otherwise, I know PayPal can process credit-cards even without registering (for non-members, like a temporary transaction) - thus dealing with all the CC details on your behalf. Have you tried this?

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your great reply. I will try this. Hopes you will be there further helps:)

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark as Answer for the other members... 10x